# google colab runtime disconnects after 90 minutes even if I am constantly working on it

Tags: deep-learning, conv-neural-network, google-colaboratory

I keep on typing in the google Colaboratory but it has happened three times now I left for like 2 minutes to check of some other things onto a web browser, at the same time 90 minutes finished and the runtime disconnected, which mean it wasn't idle for 90 minutes, it just disconnects me after 90 minutes anyways. Does it have to do with where I live maybe? India

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue many times due to bad internet, if that's not case switch to GPU runtime and try.